# Как сделать TextView кликабельным на ViewPager

Tags: android

Использую `ViewPager` для пролистывания страниц. Необходимо сделать `TextView` кликабельным, чтобы при нажатии на `TextView` появлялось новое `TextView` под существующим. Предположим, на странице отображается `R.string.inter_1_1`, а под ним при нажатии появляется `R.string.inter_2_1` (ещё не инициализировал), затем, листаешь вправо - появляется `R.string.inter_1_2`, и при нажатии `R.string.inter_2_2`, но не знаю как это реализовать в данном активити.

Догадываюсь, что нужно использовать `onClick` для `TextView` + для второго `TextView` сделать `notVisible`, и при нажатии, чтобы становился `visible`, но я не знаю, как показать ему, что нужно при нажатии именно определенное слово открывать, чтобы например, при втором пролистывании в `TextView1` появлялось `R.string.inter_1_3`, нажав на него в `TextView2`(находящимся под `TextView1`) появлялось `R.string.inter_2_3`. Соответственно, для 4-го, 4-е, и т.д.
Есть у кого-нибудь идеи? Буду весьма признателен.

```
public class Inter_1_Swipe_Adapter extends PagerAdapter{

    private int[] car = {R.string.inter_1_1, R.string.inter_1_2,
            R.string.inter_1_3, R.string.inter_1_4, R.string.inter_1_5};
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public Inter_1_Swipe_Adapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return car.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view==(RelativeLayout)object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_of_inter_inter_1_swipe, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.inter_1_textView);
        textView.setText(car[position]);
        container.addView(item_view);
        return item_view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((RelativeLayout)object);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переопределенный вами метод `instantiateItem()` возвращает одним из аргументов позицию - *int position*, это номер вашей страницы. Вы можете использовать его для создания нужной вам логики.

Для начала вам потребуется еще один массив со значениями для `textView2`.

Затем вы "вешаете" слушатель на `textView1` и в обработке клика меняете видимость для `textView2`.

Дальше все просто - в `textView2`выводите значение второго массива со строками по позиции, которая будет соответствовать странице.

```
private int[] car = {R.string.inter_1_1, R.string.inter_1_2,
            R.string.inter_1_3, R.string.inter_1_4, R.string.inter_1_5};
private int[] car2 = {R.string.inter_2_1, R.string.inter_2_2,
            R.string.inter_2_3, R.string.inter_2_4, R.string.inter_2_5};

...

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_of_inter_inter_1_swipe, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.inter_1_textView);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
               TextView textView2 = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.inter_1_textView2);
               textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               textView.setText(car2[position]);
            }

        });
        textView.setText(car[position]);
        container.addView(item_view);
        return item_view;
    }
```

Это не протестированный код, он лишь демонстрирует алгоритм.

PS: для лучшего понимания вашего кода следуйте рекомендациям конвенции, в частности по написанию имен, так имена экземпляров классов и переменных должны быть в LowCamelCase-стиле, то есть не `item_view`, а `itemView` и тд. Через нижнее подчеркивание пишутся только названия файлов ресурсов, такие как разметка, картинки и тд. , но не имена ID виджетов: не `inter_1_textView`, а `interTextView1`

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо!!! +1 к карме)

Comment: Возник ещё один вопрос относительно ViewPagera и VoiceRecognition, возможно ли их совместное применение? [ссылка на вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/465129/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-speech-to-text-%D0%B8-viewpager)